# How to control tic marks and their values in gnuplot tics

Tags: plot, gnuplot, gnu, xticks

My plot has logx axis. So I want to show the tic marks. But due to the size of the tic values they overlap. For example: [image]

But if I reduce the tic marks by the command

> set xtics (1.0e-7,1.0e-5, 5.0e-4);

It becomes like [image]

I want those logarithmic tics(like the first picture) but only three values written(like the second picture) without compromising the size. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you basically want keep all the auto tics and grid lines, but remove `1e-6` and `1e-4` tic labels and add a `5e-4` tic label.

You could do it the following way. Check `help xtics` and `help format specifiers`.

**Code:**

```
### set custom tics
reset session

set xrang[1e-7:5e-4]
set logscale x
set grid x,y
set format x "%.0t x 10^{%T}"
set rmargin 5

set xtics add ('' 1e-6, '' 1e-4, 5e-4)
plot x
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]